# Find the complete path of selected Item in a sandboxed application using objective c

Tags: objective-c, sandbox, findersync

I need to find the complete path of the selected file or folder using some function in `Objective-C`. It is a sandboxed application, hence it is not working openly for all methods.

Kindly let me know if anything is available.

Comment: What code are you currently using that's not giving you the full path?

Comment: selectedItemUrls in Finder Sync Extensions . It gives me full path but maximum limit is restricted to 10 files

Comment: I dont want a limit on the number of selected files. I also tried using NSOpenPanel and com.apple.finder arrayByApplyingSelector but both didnt work. Is there any other way out